# htaccess: redirect to a same page, but with different query string value

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, query-string

I have a page with query string which I would like to redirect to same page with different query string value:

`www.mysite.com/pages/page.php?id=5` (this is the old page)
`www.mysite.com/pages/page.php?id=7` (this is the new page that need to redirect to)

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=5$ [NC]

RewriteRule ^pages/page\.php$ pages/page.php?id=7 [R=301,L]
```

It doesn't work. Could anybody help me? Thanks!

Comment: where is your `.htaccess` file? in  root dir or `pages`?

Comment: And you want it to be external redirect? or internal?

Comment: it needs to change in the address bar too, I don't know if this helps.

Comment: As a note: you probably want to do this in PHP, and not mod_rewrite. AFAICS there's no way to query the query string safely in htaccess, so you'll either end up with not enough redirects (i.e. `?id=5&PHPSESSID=...` won't work) or too much (i.e. `?id=51` would match if you made it too greedy).

Comment: In any case, try prepending the path with a slash, i.e. `^pages/page\.php$` to `^/pages/page\.php$`.

Comment: I have tried to prepend \, but it doesn't solve the problem

Comment: if my answer didn't solve the problem,please send rewrite log or tell us what happens?

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=5$ [NC]

RewriteRule ^pages/page\.php$   http://%{HTTP_HOST}/pages/page.php?id=7 [R=301,L,NC]
```

Comment: I have try that with no result

Comment: Well, basically, same page that is requested (old one) just loads

Comment: I edited my answer! If it didn't help try to clear your cache and try again!

Comment: Look, rewrite rule is fine, the only problem I can guess is your browser cached redirect!